# Creating Tag for Cases through a Trigger

Tags: apex, tag

Currently, I am trying to create some Case Tags for my Case during an after insert event.

Essentially, all I am doing is taking a legacy field and splitting it, getting all the distinct tags. However, I don't know how to create a new `CaseTag` record.

Here is the code I have so far for my handler:

```
public static void CreateCaseTagsFromLegacyTags(List<Case> casesWithTags)
{
    List<CaseTag> newCaseTags = new List<CaseTag>();

    for(Case caseWithTag : casesWithTags)
    {
        //I pre-filtered the records prior, so this value is never null
        //or empty
        List<String> tags = caseWithTag.LegacyTags__c.split(' ');

        for(String tag : tags)
            newCaseTags.add(new CaseTag(/* What goes there? */));
    }

    INSERT newCaseTags;
}
```

So has anyone created a tag through apex before? I don't see why that not. I tried finding any example on how to do that and I could not find a single case where it was done (pun intended). So if there is any way to make this possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs on what the CaseTag object is comprised of.

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casetag.htm

From what I can read, you'll need to replace `CaseTag(/* What goes there? */)`
with the following:

```
CaseTag(
    Name = tag, //tag name
    ItemId = caseWithTag.Id, //Id of Tagged Item -- in your scenario, this is the case
    Type = 'Public' //other option is 'Private'
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you change `TagDefinitionId` to `ItemId`, it will save. I will be testing my import shortly. To confirm if it works.

Comment: Shoot, good catch!  I'll update the answer,